# jquery plugin that combines list with tabular items?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I want to create a ul list where each li is another list where the items have several properties shown in a tabular way (so all align) and is collapsible (all open, all close, some open)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that http://www.jstree.com/ does what you want.